# Looking for a review of my ActiveRecord relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I recently just started learning RoR and I am creating a hobby project.

So some quick background: Each customer is identified by an account number. Each product sale has an account number attributed with it and the products table contains all the specific product data.

My question is - with the format I have now, is this the proper way I should be linking these tables? One of the issues I am having is filtering a group of sales based on product major. So say I have a customer and I only want to view product sales where the major is "commercial", how do I go about filtering this data? See the scope I created - but I am not sure how to use it.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_sales, :primary_key => :prodnum, :foreign_key => :prodnum
  has_many :customers, through: :sales
  scope :commercial_products, -> { where(major: 'Commercial') }
end  




class ProductSale < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer, :foreign_key => :account
    belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => :prodnum, :primary_key => :prodnum
end




class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_sales, :primary_key => :account, :foreign_key => :account
   has_many :products, through: :product_sales
end
```

and my schema

```
create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "account"
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end


   create_table "product_sales", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.integer  "account"
      t.string   "month"
      t.string   "prodnum"
      t.integer  "sales"
      t.integer  "qtyshipped"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end



create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "pcatcode"
        t.string   "pcatname"
        t.string   "major"
        t.string   "prodline"
        t.string   "brand"
        t.string   "tier"
        t.string   "prodnum"
        t.string   "proddesc"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: If you have a a finite set of majors I recommend you take a look at Active Record Enums (http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), this will allow you to store an integer on the DB instead of a String (which is more performant) and gives you access to some handy methods like: `products.commercial` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... I have a customer and I only want to view product sales where the major is "commercial", how do I go about filtering this data?

This should do it:

```
@customer.product_sales.where(product: {major: 'Commercial'})
```

PS. Your models look correct, but this bit

```
has_many :customers, through: :sales

# Probably you meant: through: product_sales
```

Comment: Thank you - this did not work however as I was getting "no such column" for the major. However this led me to do a bit of research and got me in the right direction with @customer.product_sales.joins(:product).where(:products => {:major => 'Residential'}). This is working just as I wanted it to. Thank you